# Show Column values in Password format in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid-formatter, struts2-jquery-grid

I am using struts2 jqgrid. I want to show password column values in password format in my grid.

Can we use custom formatter to show password value in bullets format?

Comment: Can you describe it more?! If you just want to show bullets for password, the safer way is to add a new property to your model fill it with bullets or star and use this newly column.

Comment: @Alireza I am using editable Grid. At the time of adding record what it will get?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
     <s:head/>
     <title>Hello World</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <s:div>Email Form</s:div>
      <s:text name="Please fill in the form below:" />
      <s:form action="hello" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <s:textfield key="email.from" name="from" />
         <s:password key="email.password" name="password" />
         <s:textfield key="email.to" name="to" />
         <s:textfield key="email.subject" name="subject" />
         <s:textarea key="email.body" name="email.body" />
         <s:token />
         <s:submit key="submit" />
     </s:form>
   </body>
```